# Heroku deployment error

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment

I've successfully pushed my app to heroku, but when I `heroku open` I get an Application error on my page.

Checking the logs I can see

```
2016-02-06T17:06:42.092148+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2016-02-06T17:06:42.092157+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation failed:
failed to compile Node.js app
2016-02-06T17:07:00.738280+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code=H81 desc="Blank ap
p" method=GET path="/" host=pacific-headland-94684.herokuapp.com request_id=9bcd
ba26-7eef-4323-baff-86e4f6cc7c11 fwd="109.175.110.196" dyno= connect= service= s
tatus=502 bytes=
```

And later on in the logs I also get

```
2016-02-09T16:20:30.835195+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2016-02-09T16:20:32.198289+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `n
ode server.js`
2016-02-09T16:20:34.904089+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw err;
2016-02-09T16:20:34.904090+00:00 app[web.1]:           ^
2016-02-09T16:20:34.904079+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:338
2016-02-09T16:20:34.904092+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (modul
e.js:278:25)
2016-02-09T16:20:34.904091+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '/app/ser
ver.js'
2016-02-09T16:20:34.904092+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFile
name (module.js:336:15)
2016-02-09T16:20:34.904093+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module.runMain (mod
ule.js:501:10)
2016-02-09T16:20:34.904094+00:00 app[web.1]:     at startup (node.js:129:16)
2016-02-09T16:20:34.904094+00:00 app[web.1]:     at node.js:814:3
2016-02-09T16:20:35.976063+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-02-09T16:20:35.977672+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to c
rashed
```

If anyone is interested for full logs, here's a link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8l261wmg99yahzc/heroku_logs.txt?dl=0

All the similar problems I googled usually happen when pushing the app to heroku, but as I've said my push was successful.

Comment: Change `require('/app/server')` to a relative path like `require('./app/server')`.

Comment: That's the deal, server.js is the name of my app and not a module, the only three modules I use are express, multer and http. Also my Procfile is `web: node server.js` could that be a problem?

Comment: Make sure that your `server.js` file is at the root of your directory since that's where it expects to find it when you have `node server.js` in your Procfile. Here's a bare-bones Node app that runs on Heroku. Has a Procfile and everything: https://github.com/danneu/koa-skeleton. Maybe it can help?

Comment: You were correct, I answered my own question down below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that git repo was not in the apps folder(named node in my case) but in a folder up one level (named app, *this folder didn't exist on local*), so when I pushed it on heroku, procfile searched for server.js in folder named app instead of the root and couldn't find anything.

After checking the pathing on GitDesktop I saw the folder structure and reinitialized the repository in a right place, pushed the changes and fixed the problem.